# PHP - Retrieve multiple records from a single mysql table and append to a string

Tags: php

I have the following table in mysql. I need to select the Hid(s) from this table and append the results to a string '$s'. It would be great if you could help.

Table name : CASES

```
Did   Hid   Year  Case
---   ---   ----  ----
 1     1    2011   6
 1     1    2012   7
 2     2    2011   40
 2     2    2012   10
```

### php code segment:

```
$did=1;
$yr=2011;
$s='';
$q="select Hid from CASES where Did=$did and Year=$yr and Case!=0 ";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($rw=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    //I need to append the Hid(s) to a String '$s' declared above
}
```

Comment: `$s.= $rw["Hid"];` which is shorthand for `$s = $s.$rw["Hid"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query works, which it looks like it might:

```
$did=1;
$yr=2011;
$s='';
$q="select Hid from CASES where Did=$did and Year=$yr and Case!=0 ";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($rw=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $s .= $rw['Hid'];
}
```

That will just give you a string with all of the Hids together.. if you want to have a character in between or something else, you could:

```
$did=1;
$yr=2011;
$s=array();
$q="select Hid from CASES where Did=$did and Year=$yr and Case!=0 ";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($rw=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $s[] = $rw['Hid'];
}
$result = implode( ',', $s );
```

$result above will end up with a comma-separated list of Hids.

Comment: Thank you everyone for posting answers and suggestions for my thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$s .= $rw['Hid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get/ retrieve the data's to an array and implode it to a string. Refer
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

for implode

Answer (score 0):

```
$did=1;
$yr=2011;
$s='';
$q="select Hid from CASES where Did=$did and Year=$yr and Case!=0 ";

    $r=mysql_query($q);
    while($rw=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $s .= $rw['hid'] . '<br />';
    }



echo $s;
```